# BIM 360 Docs how to copy file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

The [versions API endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-POST/) mentions that it can be used to make a copy of a document. It appears that the copyFrom parameter is the http encoded value of the source file urn. What is the value of relationships.item.data.type.itemsid in the example? Do I need to first create an empty file object and then provide that Id in the request body?

Answer (score 1):

The item id is the id of Data Management API the file that you want to copy from it. You can obtain it via calling:

- https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-project_id-GET
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-item-GET/

You don't have to create an empty file object, just call the API: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-POST/

For example,

Here is an RVT model with stored in Docs, and its item data is the below:

```js
{
   "type": "items",
   "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:rH_L4XJsTmeiYA4ixCVNAA",   //!<<< Item id
   "attributes": {
       "displayName": "rac_basic_sample_project.rvt",
       "createTime": "2019-09-25T06:56:26.0000000Z",
       //...
       "lastModifiedTime": "2019-09-25T06:56:27.0000000Z",
       //...
       "hidden": false,
       "reserved": false,
       "extension": {
           "type": "items:autodesk.bim360:File",
           "version": "1.0",
           "schema": {
               "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/items:autodesk.bim360:File-1.0"
           },
           "data": {
               "sourceFileName": "rac_basic_sample_project.rvt"
           }
       }
   },


   //...
}
```

Then call [https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:rH_L4XJsTmeiYA4ixCVNAA/versions](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/%7BPROJECT_ID%7D/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:rH_L4XJsTmeiYA4ixCVNAA/versions) to get its version records:

```js
{
   "type": "versions",
   "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.rH_L4XJsTmeiYA4ixCVNAA?version=1",   //!<<< Version id
   "attributes": {
       "name": "rac_basic_sample_project.rvt",
       "displayName": "rac_basic_sample_project.rvt",
       "createTime": "2019-09-25T06:56:26.0000000Z",
       //...
       "lastModifiedTime": "2019-09-25T06:57:54.0000000Z",
       //...
       "versionNumber": 1,
       "storageSize": 17813504,
       "fileType": "rvt",
       "extension": {
           "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:File",
           "version": "1.0",
           "schema": {
               "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.bim360:File-1.0"
           },
           "data": {
               "processState": "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
               "extractionState": "SUCCESS",
               "splittingState": "NOT_SPLIT",
               "reviewState": "NOT_IN_REVIEW",
               "revisionDisplayLabel": "1",
               "sourceFileName": "rac_basic_sample_project.rvt"
           }
       }
   },

   //...  
}
```

Now you want to copy a specific version `urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.rH_L4XJsTmeiYA4ixCVNAA?version=1` of this item to another folder `urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.0xaYa2rVTJuFiz7rxLCOQQ`. So, the API call will look like the following:

**Note.** The URL safe form of the version id is `urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.file%3Avf.rH_L4XJsTmeiYA4ixCVNAA%3Fversion%3D1`

```
POST https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/items?copyFrom=urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.file%3Avf.rH_L4XJsTmeiYA4ixCVNAA%3Fversion%3D1

{
   "jsonapi": {
     "version": "1.0"
   },
   "data": {
     "type": "items",
     "relationships": {
      "tip":{
            "data":{
               "type":"versions",
               "id":"1"
            }
         },
         "parent": {
             "data": {
                 "type": "folders",
                 "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.0xaYa2rVTJuFiz7rxLCOQQ"  //!<<< The folder we want to put this file
             }
         }
     }
   },
   "included":[
      {
         "type":"versions",
            "id":"1",
            "attributes":{
               "name":"rac_basic_sample_project.rvt"   //!<<< Version name
            }
      }
   ]
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you for providing this. If this is going to be added to the Forge documentation it would be helpful to note that the "type:versions" "id:1" refer to the API schema version and not the file being copied..

Comment: Just FYI, it's here: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-POST/#example-3